# Динамическое удаление LinerLayout при нажатии на соответствующий ImageButton

Tags: android-studio, android-linearlayout

У меня есть AlertDialog с RadioGroup, где можно выбрать время срабатывания напоминания. При нажатии "Добавить" на активности появляется строка.
Не могу понять как мне удалять определённую строку. Я вроде получаю id, но у меня, удаляется только последний а после вылетает с ошибкой нулевого значения для функции **removeAllViews**.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog () {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Alarm_dialog);
    final View viewAlarm = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alarm_dialog_layout, null);
    final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) viewAlarm.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupAlarm);
    final Constants constants = new Constants();
    builder.setTitle("Добавить напоминание")
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_add_notification)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setView(viewAlarm);
    radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.alarmCurrentTime:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + checkedId);
                    timeAlarm = datetimeDBdate.getTime();
                    break;
                case R.id.alarm10min:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + checkedId);
                    timeAlarm = datetimeDBdate.getTime() - constants.min10;
                    break;
                case R.id.alarm20min:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + checkedId);
                    timeAlarm = datetimeDBdate.getTime() - constants.min20;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // Кнопка ОК
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Random r = new Random();
            randomKeyAlarm = r.nextInt(5789340 - 3290345) + 3290345;

            //для отдельной строки напоминания
            final LinearLayout rowAlarm = new LinearLayout(CreateAffairActivity.this);
            final View viewAlarmRow = CreateAffairActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alarm_row, null);
            rowAlarm.addView(viewAlarmRow);

            // linearlayout, в который добавляются rowAlarm
            alarmListLayout.addView(rowAlarm);
            rowAlarm.addView(viewAlarmRow);

            // задаю для строки и кнопки одинаковый id
            remove_notification = (ImageButton) viewAlarmRow.findViewById(R.id.row_close_notification);
            remove_notification.setId(randomKeyAlarm);
            rowAlarm.setId(randomKeyAlarm);

            remove_notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) alarmListLayout.findViewById(randomKeyAlarm);
                    child.removeAllViews();
                    alarmListLayout.removeView(child);
                }
            });
            dialog.dismiss(); // Отпускает диалоговое окно
        }
    });
    return builder.show();
}
```

Код для строки **alarm_row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_image_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_notification"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/row_date_notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/row_close_notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_remove_notification" />
</LinearLayout>
```

и layout куда выводятся строки **alarmListLayout**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/alarmListLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, `randomKeyAlarm` у Вас является переменной класса и при создании новой строки она формирует ID текущей строки, при этом ID предыдущих строк теряется безвозвратно. Вот и получается, что при удалении берётся ID последней добавленной строки, а затем, при последующем удалении, пытается найти уже удалённую строки, что и вызывает NPE. Вам необходимо сузить область видимости `randomKeyAlarm` до блока, где она инициализируется.

Comment: да проблема кажется в этом. Но где её инициализировать надо, чтобы оно не терялось? Оно всё время перезаписывается

Comment: теряться оно не будет, уйдёт в слушатель с уникальным ID. Объявить там же, где и присваивается. final естественно.

Comment: и ещё... не исключена ситуация, что `Random()` выдаст одинаковые номера. Могу порекомендовать метод `View.generateViewId()` вместо `Random()` либо заносить ID в коллекцию и контролировать дубликаты